# Filter by nested object in list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Can someone please advise on how to filter by nested objects in LINQ.
I have a simple 1 -> many relationship object:

```
public class WaybillReferences
{
    public int WaybillID { get; set; }
    public string WaybillNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime? WaybillDate { get; set; }
    public string FromBCentre { get; set; }
    public string ToBCentre { get; set; }
    public string FromCustomer { get; set; }
    public string ToCustomer { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PODDate { get; set; }
    public string Signee { get; set; }
    public int? BillingCustomerID { get; set; }
    public List<Order> orderReferences { get; set; }
}
```

AND

```
public class Order
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int WaybillId { get; set; }

}
```

Now my goal is to provide a filter to the user that will search for that #value in the WaybillReference.WaybillNo AND also in the List.Id's
This is what I've tried:

```
 var data = (from w in _context.Waybill
            join fromCust in _context.Customer on w.PickupCustId equals fromCust.Id
            join toCust in _context.Customer on w.DeliverCustId equals toCust.Id
            join fromBC in _context.Bcentre on fromCust.Pcode equals fromBC.Id
            join toBC in _context.Bcentre on toCust.Pcode equals toBC.Id
            select new WaybillReferences
            {
                WaybillID = w.Id,
                WaybillNo = w.CourierWbno,
                WaybillDate = w.Date,
                PODDate = w.Poddate,
                Signee = w.Signee,
                FromCustomer = fromCust.Name,
                ToCustomer = toCust.Name,
                FromBCentre = fromBC.Name,
                ToBCentre = toBC.Name,
                BillingCustomerID = w.BillCust,
                orderReferences = _context.Order.Where(y => y.WaybillId == w.Id).ToList()
            }).Where(x => BillCustomers.Contains(x.BillingCustomerID)
                   && (fromDate == null || x.WaybillDate >= fromDate)
                   && (toDate == null || x.WaybillDate <= toDate)
                   && (FilterBy.Equals("#") || x.WaybillNo.StartsWith(FilterBy))
                   && (FilterBy.Equals("#") || x.orderReferences.Any(x=> x.Id.StartsWith(FilterBy))) /*Error Here*/
           )
         .OrderBy(z => z.WaybillDate)
         .Take(300);

        return await data.ToListAsync();
```

Appreciate your time and help.

Edit:Error I get

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet .Join( outer: DbSet, inner: w => w.PickupCustId, outerKeySelector: c => (Nullable)c.Id, innerKeySelector: (w, c) => new TransparentIdentifier( Outer = w, Inner = c )) .Join( outer: DbSet, inner: ti => ti.Outer.DeliverCustId, outerKeySelector: c0 => (Nullable)c0.Id, innerKeySelector: (ti, c0) => new TransparentIdentifier, Customer>( Outer = ti, Inner = c0 )) .Join( outer: DbSet, inner: ti0 => ti0.Outer.Inner.Pcode, outerKeySelector: b => b.Id, innerKeySelector: (ti0, b) => new TransparentIdentifier, Customer>, Bcentre>( Outer = ti0, Inner = b )) .Join( outer: DbSet, inner: ti1 => ti1.Outer.Inner.Pcode, outerKeySelector: b0 => b0.Id, innerKeySelector: (ti1, b0) => new TransparentIdentifier, Customer>, Bcentre>, Bcentre>( Outer = ti1, Inner = b0 )) .Where(ti2 => __BillCustomers_0.Contains(ti2.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.BillCust) && False || ti2.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Date >= __fromDate_1 && True && False || __FilterBy_2 == "" || ti2.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.CourierWbno != null && __FilterBy_2 != null && ti2.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.CourierWbno.StartsWith(__FilterBy_2) && DbSet .Where(o => o.WaybillId == ti2.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Id) .ToList() .Any(c => False || __FilterBy_2 == "" || c.Id != null && __FilterBy_2 != null && c.Id.StartsWith(__FilterBy_2)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: what is the problem with your attempt? What is the error you get?

Comment: Added the error.